# WebLogic load jar without class file?

Tags: java, jar, weblogic, bea

I'm currently working on a prebuilt application running on weblogic.
The application consist in NAME_APPLICATION.jar that must be deployed on weblogic.
My problem is that I can't analyze anything for the simple reason that the jar **DOES NOT CONTAIN ANY .JAVA OR .CLASS FILE**
The jar just contain the following files:
- APPLICATION_1.0.sources
- APPLICATION_1.0.space
- APPLICATION.ws
- GET_SOMETHING.ds
- GET_SOMETHING.service
I really don't understand it. Where is the application ? How weblogic knows the logic (forgive me the pun) of the app? How to edit the application and where is the source files?
It's the first time that I see such Jar file, it's probably because I'm a weblogic beginner 
Thanks

Comment: I suspect this is an Oracle Web Center Spaces http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/webcenter.1111/e10147/Topic_4.1.htm application jar that you possess. But those still contain web.xml to start with

Comment: I still don't understand :-(, by the way, the xml it's not present in the jar

Comment: even i cannot find an example jar, but the extensions .spaces, .ws = web services, .service etc lead me to believe this is an OWC Spaces jar. OWC is similar to Weblogic Portal and runs on Weblogic Server

Comment: i also suspect - may be im wrong - this is an additoinal library jar and not the only jar for the app to run, is there no war file or anything?

Comment: One more hint: in this project is envolved ODSI does it helps ?

Answer (score 1):

These are resources that must be available on the classpath for the application to find them and access them.  I am guessing that the documentation tells you to deploy it as a shared library.

If they are binary files (not text files that you could try reading with a text editor), then whatever application needs them obviously knows their format and how to read them.